# Can Node and Rails share database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, postgresql

I have a Rails app which is using Postgresql. I want to make a new Node + React Native app and I want to use the same database (usernames, passwords and other details will be shared).

I saw lots of sources which are explaining how to set up Postgresql on Node, but how do I set up an existing database? For the dev environment it is stored locally if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, and there tons of tutorials that show you how to connect to postgres from node like [this one](http://mherman.org/blog/2015/02/12/postgresql-and-nodejs/#.WrxI2dNuYWo).

Comment: I think you can make both connected with API. You can make API in rails. After that you can use in node + react native.

Comment: @akbarbin will i need a database in node this way?

Comment: If you create API in rails, your node doesn't need database. Node and React Native just call the API that you've made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use this package.

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize

This is a connector for nodejs and postgresql.

But I suggest you do not use both of them handle database migration at the same time.

You can use rails to handle the migration. And just implement the database query in nodejs.

Comment: Would you recommend using `sequelize` for ORM?